# Elements of a C# List

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am using List.ElementAt(0) and List.ElementAt(1) to get the elements I need. How ever I don't want to hardcode 0 and 1 is there any other way in C#

Comment: What other conditions you have? Otherwise I don't see how you could explicitly avoid 0 and 1.

Comment: What is wrong with hardcoding 0 and 1? You ARE assuming you have 2 elements in your list anyway.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? you can place a variable (of type int for example) instead of 0 and 1 and assign to it the wanted value..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List.First() will work.  However, you really shouldn't be using ElementAt if you can help it -- it's slow.  And since you're using a list you can indeed help it.  Use the indexer instead (List[0], List[1]).

Comment: Under the hood, ElementAt checks if the source IEnumerable is a List. If it is, it uses the indexer.

Comment: @BFree, wow, didn't expect to see that in Enumerable.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It does the same thing for Count()...

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable?

```
List.ElementAt(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use a variable instead of hardcoding it. Also if it is a list you could directly use the indexer property: `list[0]`